# MySQL get all rows except first, for all rows that share the same field values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with multiple rows that have a common field value "owner_id", and I would like to get all matching rows except the first one for each. So, the query should return the rows with the "ID" 2,3,5,6 in the example table below.

```
-----------------------
| ID | VALUE | USER_ID |
-----------------------
|  1 | 11111 |    1    |
------------------------
|  2 | 22222 |    1    |
------------------------
|  3 | 33333 |    1    |
------------------------
|  4 | 11111 |    2    |
------------------------
|  5 | 22222 |    2    |
------------------------
|  6 | 33333 |    2    |
------------------------
```

Here is the code I had before I was given the solution:

```
  public function get_follow_ups()
  {
    $this->db->select('a.id, a.created_at, a.user_id, month(b.created_at) AS user_month');
    $this->db->from('entries a, users b');
    $this->db->order_by('a.created_at');
    $this->db->where('a.user_id = b.id');
    $this->db->where('day(a.created_at) != day(b.created_at)');
    $this->db->where('a.owner_id', $this->_owner_id);
    return $this->db->get();
  }
```

Sometimes the user did not make an entry on the same day they registered, causing the first entry to be included in the query when using this function.

Given the idea to create a subquery, I have modified the function to the following:

```
public function get_follow_ups()
{
  $this->db->select('MIN(created_at)')->from('entries')->group_by('user_id');
  $subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();
  $this->db->select('a.id, a.created_at, a.user_id, month(b.created_at) AS user_month');
  $this->db->from('entries a, users b');
  $this->db->order_by('a.created_at');
  $this->db->where('a.user_id = b.id');
  $this->db->where("a.created_at NOT IN ($subQuery)", NULL, FALSE);
  $this->db->where('a.owner_id', $this->_owner_id);
  return $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I'm not new to stack exchange and I did research this, but everything I read and tried came nowhere close to what I am trying to achieve. I wanted to spare everyone reading a lot of "worthless" code, but next time I include it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it seems like it would be easier to just disregard the first result for each user in the application.

Comment: I tried that, but maybe the way I coded it was bad... the query returns a few hundred thousand rows and it was taking ages to generate the final data this way.

Comment: @JohanoFierra did you try the code I posted in answer?

Comment: @JohanoFierra That's perfect, then! Just edit your question with the actual code you tried, people will be less inclined to downvote if they feel you are not just asking for a solution. Do post what you have tried, even (actually especially) if it does not work.

Comment: @Felix, I revise my code until I get it working the way I want. I don't have a code history of the different approaches I tried, and even the last attempt at removing the lines via php code is now gone. ElChupacabra pretty much hit the nail on the head, I was not aware I can simply use "NOT IN".

Comment: @JohanoFierra I did not copy paste a comment, I explained to you the probable reason for the downvotes as well as how to properly engage with the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group rows by user_id and select min ID for each group. Then select all rows excluding those you selected previously.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM your_table GROUP BY USER_ID)
```